# Java program to write csv is going to next tab

Tags: java, file, streamwriter

HiExperts

I am writing simple write csv program in java and I would need to have 3 headers and values in next row for each header. basically the content needs to go 2 next tab. but it working instead its writing in same cell.

```
            try {
                File file =new File("C:\\test\\working.csv");

                System.out.println("create new file"+(int)file.length());
                if(!file.exists()){
                    file.createNewFile();      
                }
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true); 

            // No need give the headers Like: id, Name on builder.append 
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
                if((int)file.length()==0) {
                String header = "Name"+'\t' +"Desc"+'\t'+"check"+'\t';
                bw.write(header);
                }
                bw.append('\n');        
                bw.write("test");
                bw.append('\t');
                bw.write("happy");
                bw.append('\t');
                bw.write("working");
                bw.close();
                System.out.println("Data successfully appended at the end of file");

            }
```

I have provided the sample code. I used /t. but still its writing i same cell.

I need 3 header and 3 values in next row. can someone please assist here and let me knw what is missing, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a TSV (tab-separated value) file, not a CSV (comma-separated value) file.

If you open it in your spreadsheet application, you need to import it as a TSV file or indicate that the <kbd>tab</kbd> character is used as a value-separator.

Comment: Hi... It worked now ! with the same...i added comma seperated.